# File not found when execution a bat file from a java program

Tags: java

I have this code that used to work, but now I´m getting that the program can´t find the file but the file is there.

This is my code. My project is in `C:\Users\user\git\project` and the apps folder is `C:\Users\user\git\apps\folder`.

```
        ProcessBuilder pb = null;
       pb = new ProcessBuilder("myApp.bat");                         
        pb.directory(newFile("C:\Users\user\git\project\..\apps\folder"));
        File log = new File("log");
        pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
        pb.redirectOutput(Redirect.appendTo(log));

        Process p = pb.start();
      assert pb.redirectInput() == Redirect.PIPE;
      assert pb.redirectOutput().file() == log;
      assert p.getInputStream().read() == -1;
```

And I´m getting  `Cannot run program "myApp.bat" (in directory "C:\Users\user\git\project\..\apps\folder"): CreateProcess error=2, Can´t find file`

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying an incorrect folder path for your bat file.

You are specifying

`C:\Users\user\git\project\..\apps\folder`

but you are saying that the correct folder is `C:\Users\user\git\project\..\apps\folder`.

Change the line

`pb.directory(newFile("C:\Users\user\git\project\..\apps\folder"));`

to

`pb.directory(newFile("C:\Users\user\git\project\apps\folder"));`

The `..` refers to change in directory. So your actual path becomes
C:\Users\user\git\apps\folder instead of C:\Users\user\git\project\apps\folder

Comment: apps and project are in the same level. What I actually do is getProjectPath+/../apps/folder/miApp.bat

Comment: In the error message you have posted, the final folder that end up passing is `C:\Users\user\git\project\..\apps\folder`. Show your actual code so that people don't get sidetracked.

Comment: that´s the place where the file is. Before that I do  new File("C:\Users\user\git\project/../apps/folder/miApp.bat").exists() and it returns true

Comment: Is that myApp.bat or miApp.bat?

Comment: Is myApp.bat, but it doesn´t make a diference